# Replacing NAs with mean of next non-NA value

Tags: r, missing-data, zoo

I got a data.frame with hourly values. Sometimes I miss values for a number of hours and want to fill that up with the first non missing value devided by the count of missing values +1 (non missing value also part of it:

i.e. (Very simplified version)

```
 c(1,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,2,1)
```

And what I want it to be:

```
c(1,(4/4),(4/4),(4/4),(4/4),(2/2),(2/2),1)
```

Which will be:

```
c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Currently i use the zoo with na.locf which replaces all NA with the first non na: for our example this means:

```
c(1,4,4,4,4,2,2,1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine `na.locf` and `rle`:

```
library(zoo)

ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(c(0, head(x,-1))), 
       with(rle(na.locf(x, fromLast=T)), rep(values/lengths, lengths)), 
       x)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

It works also for:

```
x = c(1, NA, 5, 3, 3, NA, NA, 1)
#[1] 1.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 3.0000000 3.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```